# How to make a cloud and all platforms offline apps together?

Tags: google-app-engine, cloud

I know is hard to develop web application and make a individual app versions in each device.
But i just want to know how that works with big companies.I want to know how they write there code

The best example is Evernote and Google Drive.
They make a cloud application and individual apps for each device.

So the questions are..

How do sync the data with the cloud apps ?
Do they use version control ?

Can i get software requirement specification anywhere ?

Platforms and Languages:

- iPhone and Mac - Objective C
- Android and Other Mobile Apps - Java
- Windows 8 - C#
- Web Apps - PHP or Python

**How do you solve this solution languages differ?**
I guess i it's not possible with version control..

**How to minimize coding ?**

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you use a version control tool.

> make a individual app versions in each device.

I assume you mean developing different versions with few differences. The branch feature in a version tool can help you manage these versions easily.

> How do sync the data with the cloud apps ?

You can use the web deployment feature to upload the applications/modifications to your web server.

I list some version control tools here for your reference:

1. Git
2. SVN
3. SourceAnywhere (I work for the company)
4. Team Foundation Server

Comment: You are right, But the thing is for different apps i need to use different apps.


Example :
iPhone and Mac - Objective C ,
Android and Other Mobile Apps - Java ,
Windows 8 - C#,
Web Apps - PHP or Python ,

**How do you solve this solution?**
I guess i it's not possible with version control..